# Выравнивание div по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть следующий код:

```css
.about-me-block {
  width: auto;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #CAF7E2;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.profile-block {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #456990;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F45B69;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.profile-text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E4FDE1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me-block">
  <div class="profile-block">
    <div class="profile-image"></div>
    <div class="profile-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как мне выровнять по центру горизонтали `profile-text`, не используя отступы? Пытался при помощи `vertical-align`, но не получилось.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант с абсолютным позиционированием:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-me-block {
  width: auto;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #CAF7E2;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.profile-block {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #456990;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F45B69;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.profile-text {
  /*BEGIN*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*END*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E4FDE1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me-block">
  <div class="profile-block">
    <div class="profile-image"></div>
    <div class="profile-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант с `Flexbox`:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-me-block {
  width: auto;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #CAF7E2;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.profile-block {
  /*BEGIN*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*END*/
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #456990;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F45B69;
}

.profile-text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E4FDE1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me-block">
  <div class="profile-block">
    <div class="profile-image"></div>
    <div class="profile-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший полный ответ (+)

Comment: @Arthur , спасибо большое

Comment: @НовиковМаксим, пожалуйста=)